# Django/guardian default permission

Tags: django, django-guardian

What I would like to do is to set view permissions of certain parts of the site depending on the user (that is easy using permissions and guardian).

I have a set of buttons across the top of the page. For one or two buttons I want to set permissions for only a few users or groups to be able to see that button.  That part is fine (using guardian).

Each button is related to a model instance. The model has a view_button permission.  Is there a way to have the view_button permission be default to True if the permissions is empty?  Or, is there a way of saying has_perm be True for all users?

Maybe I could just create a static method within the model that does that check for me. Is there a better way to do it?